# '12 Honda CR-V rear seat removal

Tags: honda, crv, seat

Can someone pls provide instructions for removing the bottom part of the rear seats on a 4th gen CR-V?  Maybe provide service manual illustrations?

I found instructions on this forum for removing the seat back part of the rear seats. But no info on the bottom (cushion) part of the seat that flips up.

And yes, I really do want the rear seats to be completely removed from the car.  All rear seat parts out.